# Assign an ID-variable based on multiple columns

Tags: python, pandas, group-by

I have two datasets containing the same firms, but at times slightly differently named. Additionally, the same company may show up under different names *within* a particular dataset. To identify which firms belong together, I created an auxiliary dataframe which links company names in the two datasets. The resulting dataframe may look like this.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

d = {'dataset_1': ["company A", "comp. A", "company A", "comp. A","company B", "b company", "company c"], 'dataset_2': ["company A", "company A", "comp. a", "comp. a", "company B", "company B", "company c"]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)
print df
```

I.e. `company A` in `dataset`*`1` *is equal to `company A` in `dataset2`, `comp. A` in `dataset`*`1` *is equal to `company A` in `dataset_2` etc. What I am trying to achieve is to create an ID for each firm. I.e. I would like to automatically create the following table:

```
d = {'dataset_1': ["company A", "comp. A", "company A", "comp. A","company B", "b company", "company c"], 'dataset_2': ["company A", "company A", "comp. a", "comp. a", "company B", "company B", "company c"], 'id': [1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 3]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)
print df
```

What I have tried is to group by company names and to assign an ID. But I find it challenging to write code which identifies these groups. I.e. I can...

```
group = df.groupby(["dataset_1"])

df['id'] = group.ngroup()
```

But this obviously creates not the groups I would like to create. Can someone think of a way to solve this issue?

Comment: using [`networkx`](https://networkx.org/): `df['id'] = df['dataset_1'].map({n: i for i, g in enumerate(nx.connected_components(nx.from_pandas_edgelist(df, source='dataset_1', target='dataset_2')), start=1) for n in g})`

Comment: That worked! Thank you so much @mozway